# How to make a IF condition in query?

Tags: mysql

How do i make a query like this in mysql ? is that possible? i'd like to search if the table was existing then if yes it is existing execute the `SELECT * FROM tbl_employee_debitcredit` and if not then it is going to else.

```
IF (SELECT EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'db_hrms_eiger' 
    AND table_name = 'tbl_employee_debitcredit')) = 1 THEN 
SELECT * FROM tbl_employee_debitcredit

Else
'Do Nothing
```

How do i do this in a correct way? i based the code in vb.net.

Comment: This has got nothing at all to do with VB.NET so I removed that tag.

Comment: You can't do this with normal SQL, it would have to been done from a stored procedure.

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? Normally, applications are written to work with a predefined database schema, and this schema should include the table `tbl_employee_debitcredit`. Exceptions might be applications to work on database schemas or applications that need to work with different versions of a schema, but in those cases you wouldn't want to hide the non-existance of the table within some SQL statement, but you want to have precise information in the app to perform the correct database operations.

Comment: I have 5 database with different connection those 5 database has some structure that doesn't have to the other database ,those 5 database is inside of for loop i only have 1 query on that loop. That's why i'm having a problem and i'd like to check it first if does have a table before executing the query. @Hans-MartinMosner

Comment: @ClaritaMunggo ok so that's equivalent to the case of working with different schema versions. Just do two SQLs in your loop, one to check for the existence of the table, the second to do the actual select. You may want to cache the existence information somewhere, it's unlikely that the table will spontaneously appear or disappear in one of the databases.

Comment: I will try that. @Hans-MartinMosner

Answer (score 0):

I had never seen this approach.
You can write store procedures, then call it anywhere that you need.